# Set the content length for of a dynamical created image in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http

I'm looking for easy way to set the content length of a dynamical created image in the Http Response.

```
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
Response.Clear();
Response.BufferOutput = true; 
...
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
...
bmp.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
Response.Flush();
```

Trying to do set the content length with

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", Response.OutputStream.Length())
```

Gives unexpected results.

Also I don't wish to copy the file into another stream (say MemoryStream) and copy it again to the output stream.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Does your HTTP server class support chunked encoding? If so, just use that and you don't need to set the size and you still permit connection keep alive.

Comment: @Eden, you have to store image into the mem-stream and measure the content length. OTOH, why not push the image on the disk and then serve it from there using Reponse.WriteFile (or TransmitFile). This way only make sense if you have to serve the same image many times (essentially your are caching it on the disk) to (possibly) multiple users.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - From the documentation it seems that IIS 7.5 supports chunked encoding although I don't see this in the response headers. I'll have to investigate this issue. Thanks!

Comment: @VinayC unfortunately images can not be cached on the disk, each response is unique.

Answer (score 4):

```
long bmpByteSize;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(estimatedLength /* you can instantiate without this parameter at all */))
{
    bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
    bmpByteSize= ms.Length;
}
```

Comment: This the exact thing I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: You must. Alternatively, see @David Schwartz's comment; you didn't respond to him.

Comment: No. There are many options. I can for example write my own HttpResponse class that does what I need.

Comment: We're talking about realistic solutions. If you have the time to handcraft your own `HttpResponse` class just for this, then go for it. Just please submit your class code here for the sake of everyone else who will look for solutions to your problem.

Comment: The box is a good place. Maybe the solution is to replace Bitmap with another alternative ? say FreeImage  (http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/sourcecode.html) ?